# TypeError: object.__new__ has no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.3

Here is the code:

```
class Display:
    def ___init___(self,width,height):
        self.screenWidth = width
        self.screenHeight = height
        #self.background1 = pygame.image.load("background1.png")
        #self.backplace = self.background1.get_rect()
        # Initialize screen

        self.size = self.width, self.height = self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
        # Loaded only once to save time
        #self.healthImage = pygame.image.load("healthbetter.png").convert_alpha()
        self.somethingChanged = False   # Nothing changed, no need to draw screen
        self.scrollOffset = 0
        mathclass = Mathclass(self.screen)
```

This is the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Noam\My Documents\games by me\first project\first project.py", line 302, in <module>
    display = Display(640,480)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters"
```

I cannot find anything that helps me with this specific error. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4):

You have put a extra set of underscores when only two are required for [magic methods](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), instead try this:

```
def __init__(self,width,height):
```